# Can I exclude a folder from the EPIC syntax checker?

Tags: eclipse, perl, epic

Using Eclipse (Indigo r2) + EPIC (0.5.46), I'd like to exclude a specific file/folder from the syntax checker.  Is this possible?

When attempting to execute any script within the project, I am prompted with:

```
Errors in Workspace
Errors exist in required project(s):
...
Proceed with launch?
```

The warning is benign and does not need to be addressed prior to launch.